# how to calculate datediff in row

Tags: mysql, sql

**table patient**

[image]

[image: downarrow]

**table admission**

[image]

**table tbl_master**

[image]

[image: downarrow]

**tbl_action**

[image]

I need calculate different time fibrinolytic_datetime - admission_datetime and table admission field Fibrinolytic is SK.

I try

```
SELECT   
       admission.AN,
       admission.HN,
       pat_name,
       pat_lname,
       Fibrinolytic,
       DATEDIFF(date_time,(SELECT date_time from tbl_action WHERE tbl_id = "tbl001"))
FROM patient,admission,tbl_action
WHERE admission.HN = patient.HN AND admission.AN = tbl_action.AN
AND Fibrinolytic = "SK" AND tbl_id = "tbl002"
```

But response from phpmyadmin `"Subquery returns more than 1 row"`

I want total
[image]

Comment: exactly as the error says - you're using a subquery in a context where it can return only a SINGLE value, but it's actually returning multiple values. in this case, it's returning date_time values for rows AN001/tbl001, AN002/tbl001, AN003/tbl001

Comment: Why not you join  your  `tables`  from inner join?

Comment: If you provide SqlFiddle or Schema it would be better

Comment: @JojoeAloha : your sqlfiddle is empty

Comment: Sorry. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a40af

Comment: @JojoeAloha check this and let me know it is ok ?http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a40af/10

Comment: No.DATEDIFF incorrect. Correct tbl002-tbl001

Answer (score 0):

Join Your Tables From `Inner Join`  instead of `Cross Join`

Your Sub Query returning more then 1 values because you have 3 rows in your Table `tbl_action` against `tbl_Id = "tbl001"`

`SELECT date_time from tbl_action WHERE tbl_id = "tbl001"`

You have to uniquely identify the date_time which  you are looking for by adding some unique id in the where clause of this query

`SELECT date_time from tbl_action WHERE tbl_id = "tbl001" and AN ="AN001"`

**Edit**

```
SELECT   
       admission.AN,
       admission.HN,
       pat_name,
       pat_lname,
       Fibrinolytic,
       DATEDIFF(date_time,(SELECT date_time from tbl_action WHERE tbl_id = "tbl001" and AN ="AN001"))
FROM patient
inner join admission on admission.HN = patient.HN 
inner join tbl_action on admission.AN = tbl_action.AN
WHERE  admission.Fibrinolytic = "SK" AND tbl_action.tbl_id = "tbl002"
```

Comment: I use this sql error "Subquery returns more than 1 row "

Comment: @JojoeAloha : See my edited answer i have added another condition in your sub query now it should work as expected